# Does convexity of a function guarantee tractability of finding its minimum?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization

Formulating a problem as a convex optimization problem usually implicitly considered to imply being able to find global minimizer of the objective. My question is that if it is true or not.

Generally speaking, I wonder when minimizing a convex objective is tractable and when it is not tractable?

In particular, suppose we have a convex function $f$, and need a polynomial time algorithm to find its minimum. Does convexity alone guarantee existence of such an algorithm (I guess not) or more conditions are needed?

(It is a surprise to me why this very basic question is not explicitly addressed in many relevant texts.)

Comment: It is useful to know if it is a hard question, or not well stated.

Comment: The short answer is that the only thing you need is convexity subject to some obvious conditions (you should be able to compute the function, the domain should be bounded, etc). See e.g. this paper of Lovasz and Vempala: http://www.cc.gatech.edu/~vempala/papers/vol4.ps

Comment: Can you define *tractable* more precisely? A polynomial number of iterations? A polynomial number of floating-point operations? etc. (This is kind of a leading question, actually: polynomial iteration counts are not enough.)

Comment: By tractable, I mean, the total number of (floating point) operations is polynomial in the size of input.

Comment: If you accept mild conditions on the geometry of the function, like Lipschitz continuity (for first-order methods) or self-concordance (for Newton's method), you might have polynomial iteration counts. But you still have to compute the relevant derivatives of the function, and there is no guarantee that this will be polynomial in the size of the input. And of course, there's the challenge of non-convex functions, which do still admit polynomial iteration counts, but the computational description is not straightforward.

Comment: I think the reason this "very basic question" is not explicitly addressed in relevant texts is because, well, it is actually not basic. ;-)

Comment: Thank you. Yes, "basic" is a wrong word, I should have used "fundamental" instead.

Comment: @MichaelGrant What exactly do you mean by ''... non-convex functions, which do still admit polynomial iteration counts, but the computational description is not straightforward''??